# redirect all pages to temporary page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

RedirectMatch (.*) domain.com/folder doesn't work.  Its giving me "The page isn't redirecting properly" error in ff.

Anybody have a solution?  Tried a few different ways like rewrite but I keep getting these redirect errors and 500 errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    http://domain.com/folder [R=301,L]
```

If you use only this rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$    http://domain.com/folder [R=301,L]` Apache will fall in a loop so you get the message:

`The page isn't redirecting properly`

Comment: do you change `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder$` for your path??

Comment: BTW -- 301 code is not good for such "temporary page" -- better use 302 or 307 instead.

Comment: @Ryan Tuosto Modern browser do CACHE 301 redirects. Try clearing browser cache and restart it. Alternatively try another browser to bypass such behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    http://domain.com/folder [R=301,L]
```

The R is the redirect type (Permanent/Tmeporary).  And the L means to stop processing any more rules that follow this rule if it is matched.

Also, in your httpd.conf, make sure you have set `AllowOverride All` if you are trying to do this in a .htaccess file and not in a custom config file.

Or, you could put this in your index.html:

```
<script language=javascript>
    location.replace("http://domain.com/folder");
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this.  It still gives me the "The page isn't redirecting properly" error.

Comment: Make sure your 'AllowOverride' is set to 'All' and not set to 'None'.  Also, make sure there are no rewrite rules in .htaccess/.conf for /folder that may conflict or be causing a rewrite loop.

Comment: This isn't set at all, could it be defaulting to non?

Comment: I believe it does default to None.  Try adding the line with 'AllowOverride All' near the top of the httpd.conf file.

Comment: are you sending to another host or the same??

Comment: same, i just want to redirect every page to a splash page

Comment: You could always use some javascript in your main index.html page like this:  `location.replace("http://domain.com/folder");`

Comment: @chown Your current rewrite rule most likely (depends on .htaccess location etc) will create redirect loop as it will redirect already redirected URLs. You need to have some condition like `tttony` has to stop redirecting URLs if they are already redirected.